# Gtk.Widget.get_allocated_size() returns zero-size Gdk.Rectangle for object created after Gtk.Window.show_all() is called

Tags: gtk, gtk3, pygobject

As the following simple example creates a button in a window and 2 seconds later a timer replaces it with a bigger button.

```
import gi

gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk, GLib


class ButtonWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.set_default_size(500, 200)
        
        button = Gtk.Button.new_with_label("one")
        button.set_size_request(100, 50)
        button.set_halign(Gtk.Align.CENTER)
        button.set_valign(Gtk.Align.CENTER)
        self.add(button)
        
        self.timeout_id = GLib.timeout_add(2000, self.on_timeout, button)

    def on_timeout(self, button):
        rect, _ = button.get_allocated_size()
        print(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height)
        
        self.remove(button)
        button = Gtk.Button.new_with_label("two")
        button.set_size_request(200, 100)
        button.set_halign(Gtk.Align.CENTER)
        button.set_valign(Gtk.Align.CENTER)
        self.add(button)
        self.show_all()
        
        rect, _ = button.get_allocated_size()
        print(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height)
    
win = ButtonWindow()
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Unfortunately `get_allocated_size` returns a zero rect for the larger button after it has been added to the Window even thought `show_all` is called and the new button is visible.

Also the allocated size returned is the size of the Window not the button, as the console output shows:

```
0 0 500 200
0 0 0 0
```

---

**Update**

The behaviour is identical in the native GTK3 API

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

guint timeout_id;
GtkWidget *window;
GtkWidget *button;

static gboolean on_timeout(gpointer user_data)
{
    int baseline;
    GtkAllocation rect;
    GtkWidget *button2;
    
    gtk_widget_get_allocated_size(button, &rect, &baseline);
    printf("x: %i y: %i width: %i height: %i\n", rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);
    
    gtk_container_remove(GTK_CONTAINER(window), button);
    //g_object_unref (button);  // segfault???
    
    button2 = gtk_button_new_with_label ("two");
    gtk_widget_set_size_request (button2, 200, 100);
    gtk_widget_set_halign (button2, GTK_ALIGN_CENTER);
    gtk_widget_set_valign (button2, GTK_ALIGN_CENTER);
    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER(window), button2);
    gtk_widget_show_all (window);
    
    gtk_widget_get_allocated_size(button2, &rect, &baseline);
    printf("x: %i y: %i width: %i height: %i\n", rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);
    
    g_source_remove(timeout_id);
    return 0;
}

static void activate(GtkApplication* app, gpointer user_data)
{
  window = gtk_application_window_new (app);
  gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), 500, 200);
  
  button = gtk_button_new_with_label ("one");
  gtk_widget_set_size_request (button, 100, 50);
  gtk_widget_set_halign (button, GTK_ALIGN_CENTER);
  gtk_widget_set_valign (button, GTK_ALIGN_CENTER);
  gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER(window), button);
  gtk_widget_show_all (window);
  
  timeout_id = g_timeout_add(2000, on_timeout, NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  GtkApplication *app;
  int status;

  app = gtk_application_new ("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_DEFAULT_FLAGS);
  g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);
  status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
  g_object_unref (app);

  return status;
}
```

Output:

```
x: 0 y: 0 width: 500 height: 200
x: 0 y: 0 width: 0 height: 0
```

---

**Update 2**

Here is the Python version of the correct program

```
import gi
import time

gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk, GLib

class MyButton(Gtk.Button):
    def __init__(self, label, width, height):
        Gtk.Button.__init__(self)
        self.set_label(label)
        self.connect("size-allocate", self.my_size)
        self.set_size_request(width, height)
        self.set_halign(Gtk.Align.CENTER)
        self.set_valign(Gtk.Align.CENTER)
        
    def my_size(self, obj, rect):
        print("Button dimensions", rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height)
        
class ButtonWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self)
        self.set_default_size(500, 200)
        
        button = MyButton("one", 100, 50)
        self.add(button)
        self.timeout_id = GLib.timeout_add(2000, self.on_timeout, button)

    def on_timeout(self, button):
        self.remove(button)
        button = MyButton("two", 200, 100)
        self.add(button)
        self.show_all()
    
win = ButtonWindow()
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: As far as the segfault is concern, the Gtk3 doc states for `gtk_container_remove`: "Note that container will own a reference to widget , and that this may be the last reference held; so removing a widget from its container can destroy that widget." I think the unref was already done here, so you get a segfault.

Comment: As long as the widget is not realized, you will get size allocations of 0. You could try to connect to the realize signal to see if this is the case here.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean by _realized_.

Comment: Read this : https://blogs.gnome.org/jnelson/2010/10/13/those-realize-map-widget-signals/

Comment: @BobMorane I've connected to the realize signal and I'm still getting zero dimensions.

Comment: Is the `realize` signal triggered before the code outputing `x: 0 y: 0 width: 0 height: 0`?

Comment: Ok, I just tried your code: it works here, the second button is indeed bigger. So I guess you are wondering about the 0-values. I'll take a look into that specific issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this issue, connect to the ["size-allocate"](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/signal.Widget.size-allocate.html) signal. This will be called when a new region has actually been allocated to the widget. From the handler, you can get that information:

```c
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

guint timeout_id;
GtkWidget *window;
GtkWidget *button;

// Called when dimensions is actually allocated to widget.
void on_size_allocate(GtkWidget *widget, GtkAllocation *allocation, void *data)
{
    printf("x: %i y: %i width: %i, height: %i\n", allocation->x, allocation->y, allocation->width, allocation->height);
}

static gboolean on_timeout(gpointer user_data)
{
    int baseline;
    GtkAllocation rect;
    GtkWidget *button2;
    
    gtk_container_remove(GTK_CONTAINER(window), button);
    button2 = gtk_button_new_with_label("two");
    g_signal_connect(button2, "size-allocate", G_CALLBACK(on_size_allocate), NULL);
    gtk_widget_set_size_request(button2, 200, 100);
    gtk_widget_set_halign(button2, GTK_ALIGN_CENTER);
    gtk_widget_set_valign(button2, GTK_ALIGN_CENTER);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), button2);

    gtk_widget_show(button2);
    
    g_source_remove(timeout_id);

    return 0;
}

static void activate(GtkApplication* app, gpointer user_data)
{
    window = gtk_application_window_new(app);
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW (window), 500, 200);
  
    button = gtk_button_new_with_label("one");
    g_signal_connect(button, "size-allocate", G_CALLBACK(on_size_allocate), NULL);
    gtk_widget_set_size_request(button, 100, 50);

    gtk_widget_set_halign(button, GTK_ALIGN_CENTER);
    gtk_widget_set_valign(button, GTK_ALIGN_CENTER);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), button);
    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
  
    timeout_id = g_timeout_add(2000, on_timeout, NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    GtkApplication *app;
    int status;

    app = gtk_application_new("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
    g_signal_connect(app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);
    status = g_application_run(G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
    g_object_unref(app);

    return status;
}
```

Here is the output I get from this code:

```
x: 200 y: 75 width: 100, height: 50
x: 150 y: 50 width: 200, height: 100
```

which I think is what you were looking for. From what I understand, the problem with calling `gtk_widget_set_size_request` and then calling `gtk_widget_get_allocated_size` is that the size *request* may not happen immediately. If it has not happened, the values returned by `gtk_widget_get_allocated_size` are invalid, hence your weird output. By connecting to the signal, you let GTK notify you when the size has *actually* been allocated, hence the valid values.